# github projects page be redirected to a subdomain of a already used domain?

Tags: dns, subdomain, github-pages

Here is my problem, I have a domain name that I use for my myname.github.io website (call it mydomain.com) and I want to use blog.mydomain.com for a github project page.

As I understand it, a `gh-pages` branch under a repository (myname-blog) will be served up on mydomain.com/myname-blog

Is it possible to move a project page to the subdomain of an already used domain? I cannot use a '/' in my dns management server, so if I simply point myname.github.io to blog.mydomain.com I would just be duplicating the mydomain.com stuff right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three solutions here :

- main domain on `myname.github.io` with a `CNAME` file (`mydomain.com`). `myname/blog` github repository will then be served and redirected to `mydomain.com/blog`.
- serving `mydomain.com` from `myname/blog` repository. Just add the CNAME file (`mydomain.com`) to this repository and remove CNAME from `myname.github.io` repository.
- serving `mydomain.com` from `myname.github.io` and `blog.mydomain.com` from `myname/blog` : add a CNAME (`blog.mydomain.com`) in `myname/blog` repository, and a DNS entry to `blog.mydomain.com` pointing to github DNS's

Comment: And the github dns for both repos is the same right? It's just `myname.github.com`

Comment: Solutions 1 and 2 only needs to set DNS to yourdomain.com. Solution 3 needs you to set an second DNS record according to https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/

Comment: so is this referring to an apex domain? It may be that I am new to this but the github documentation on all this seems very sparse

Comment: apex domain is `mydomain.com`. Solutions 1 and 2 are for apex and solution 3 is for subdomain.

Comment: alright so then [subdomain](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/#configuring-a-custom-subdomain-with-your-dns-provider) says to simply use `myname.github.io` as the cname entry. If so, am I correct in my first comment?